# Change download link depending on browser

Tags: javascript, html

ok so why wont this work

i have my java script

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/like Mac OS X/i)) {
                document.getElementById('down').href="http://www.google.com";
        }
</script>
</head>
```

and in the body i have

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="down"><img src="img/download.gif"/></a></div>
```

but it simply just dosnt work :/

Comment: `doesn't work` : please explain in details.

Comment: sorry its hard too expalin. it just nothing it dsnt change when i try to open the link on my iDevice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put the script in `<head>` which means that the "down" anchor element doesn't exist at the time the script is run, so there's no href to change.

Move the script to the end of body, or have the script contents run on the `load` event.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `like`:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X/i)
```